# Hiding Toolbar when setting Recycleviewer background

Tags: java, android, xml, android-recyclerview, toolbar

When I set the background paramter on my RecyclerView, it hides the Toolbar.

Simple, but I can't figure out how can I fix it.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context="los.printers.MainActivity"
    app:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_fragment_container"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fragment_printer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="los.printers.fragment_printer">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_List"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorTextIcons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

The padding  works fine in RecyclerView, but the toolbar doesn't shows up.

Comment: make recylerview below the toolbar and delete android:layout_alignParentTop="true" line see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `rl_fragment_container` is drawn on top of your toolbar.

But I think you know that because you apply a padding in your fragment.

A *padding* will draw the view in the same size and is applied to its contents, while a margin will be outside of the views bounds, making the whole view smaller. This is important if you draw backgrounds.

As said befoer, your fragment is on top of your toolbar, your recyclerview fills the whole fragment and draws a background on top.

You can now

1. move the `rl_fragment_container` *before* the toolbar in xml -> this will get it drawn below the toolbar
2. change padding to margin
3. or just layout the `rl_fragment_container` below your toolbar with `android:layout_below="@+id/tb_main"` and remove paddings & margins.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `activity_main.xml:`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        tools:context="los.printers.MainActivity"
        app:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tb_main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_fragment_container"
             android:layout_below="@+id/tb_main"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```